# Rails : get json value in hidden_field form (giphy api)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, giphy-api

I am using the Giphy search API to let my users search for gifs and let them add gif.

Here is simplified part of my code to make it works :

**_Form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for Task.new do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :gif, id: "GifUrl", value: "" %>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search gif">
<!-- This part render the gif search result -->
<div id="score"></div>
<% end %>
```

**Part of my script where I fetch the details of the gif from giphy**

```
  this.displayResult = function(url) {
    const target = document.getElementById('score');
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = url;

    target.appendChild(img);
  }
```

What I wanted to do is to scrape the html src value of the gif link returned and pass it in my form through an hidden_field, but it returns : [object Object] as a value, instead of the proper gif link.

```
 => #<Task id: 285, description: "", user_id: 37, gif: "[object Object]">
```

Should I use an html parser like nokogiri or am I doing something wrong ?
How can achieve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when using the giphy-api you get a json [response](https://github.com/Giphy/GiphyAPI#sample-response-search). You should look into just using the URL of the image size you would like to store. IE

```
$("#GifUrl").val(
  giphy_response['data'][SEARCH_RESULT_TO_USE][images][IMAGE_SIZE_TO_USE]['url']
)
```